# How to use AuthProviderPluginClass in managed package?

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata, auth-provider

I am trying to create custom Auth. Provider for my managed package. Class extending **Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass** works well in namespaced scratch org, but when packaged and installed in sandbox I am unable to save custom Auth. Provider record with following error message:

```
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Custom Metadata Type is either invalid or null . Check the returned type for getCustomMetadataType() method
```

Any of the fields from custom metadata type provided inside package are not visible on Auth. Provider page.[image]
This may be related to fact I am querying Protected metadata record present in my managed package, because I want to hide some secrets from Salesforce admin installing package. So basically I have two metadata types: `Public_Auth_Provider_Config__mdt` which is public and `Auth_Provider_Config__mdt` which is protected and hides my secrets.

In the method **global String getCustomMetadataType()** in custom auth provider I have tried multiple options.

```
global String getCustomMetadataType() {
        return 'Public_Auth_Provider_Config__mdt';  
}
```

I have tried using metadata type with or without namespace: Public_Auth_Provider_Config__mdt or xxx__Public_Auth_Provider_Config__mdt

I have came across product which uses managed package is somehow albe to use/view/save custom metadata record Auth.Provider
https://docs.incountry.com/salesforce/managing-oauth2-authentication-and-authorization/

[image]

**Question:**

How do I expose Custom metadata record fields onto Auth. Provider layout and save custom Auth. Provider inside managed package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resovled my issue but I am not sure why exactly this happened.
Inside my class extending AuthProvider plugin. I was using private class property of type `Auth_Provider_Config__mdt` which is my protected metadata type, with getter method returning queried metadata record, for further use in authentication flow.

```
private AuthProviderCredential__mdt config {
    get {
        if(config == null){
            config = [SELECT  Id, Secret_field__c FROM AuthProviderCredential__mdt LIMIT 1];
        }
        return config;
    }
    set;
}
```

This was fine in scratch org, but caused silent fail in managed package.

To make it work I removed private `config` property and just queried this record separately in every class method : `handleCallback`, `getUserInfo`, `refresh` , `initiate`. This removed fail after packing metadata and allowed me to save Auth. Provider with client provided keys to `Public_Auth_Provider_Config__mdt` record while still hide some secrets in protected type `Auth_Provider_Config__mdt`